# Probability of $C_n^k$ elements which contains at least K elements

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm trying to do a simple problem.

I have a set of integers:

$$N={1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} $$

I want to combine this elements in a set of combinations of size $k=3$ from this set, i.e. $C_6^3$, where $n=|N|$. However I want each combined set of size 3 have at least one element of set:

$$M={1, 2}$$

What's the probability of a resulting set $C_6^3$ of $N$ has at least one element of $M$?

I believe that I want the probability of my set has 1 or more elements of $M$. Using law of total probability I need the probability of the resulting set have less than 1 elements of $M$. I know that problem has a easy solution using combinations, but I want to do using law of total probability.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it's a lot simpler to just count the combinations that don't hold any of the elements of `M` (`C(4,3)`) and subtract it from the total number of combinations, if you really want to use something total-probability-like:

Of all sets of 3 items drawn from 1 to 6, the ones that have at least one element of `M` can be divided into 3 cases:

- The ones that have only 1 in them (and not 2). This implies drawing
  the remaining two elements from the 4 items not in `M`, so there are
  `C(4,2)` of these, so 6.
- The ones that have only 2 in them (and not 1). This implies, again,
  drawing the remaining two elements from the 4 items not in `M`, so
  there are `C(4,2)` of these, so 6.
- The ones that have both 1 and 2. Then you can draw the remaining item
  from the 4 items not in `M`, so there are 4 of these.

Sum these numbers up and divide by the number of combinations. If we've done everything ok, then adding the cases where no items of M were included (`C(4,3)=4`, as indicated above) should make the total equal to all possible combinations (`C(6,3)=20`), and indeed this is correct.